# How can I list the revision numbers of a document in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, revision, revisions

I know that I can retrieve a specific revision of a document via

```
http://localhost:5984/mydb/626b345059c2a54fbe8b8009ba87a409?rev=2-3696048776
```

but this assumes I know the revision number **2-3696048776**. How can I list all available revisions for document **626b345059c2a54fbe8b8009ba87a409**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can list revs info like this:
http://localhost:5984/mydb/626b345059c2a54fbe8b8009ba87a409?revs_info=true

This appears to be available on the version I'm running which is 0.10.1.